# How to deploy Hyperledger Fabric Fabcar using IPv6 address?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm working on deployment of Hyperledger Fabric Project based on Fabcar using IPv6 addresses. Our project has been running successfully using IPv4 addresses, but now we accept to replace IPv4 by IPv6.

We deploy two Fabric Nodes ,and the one is running orderer,ca,peer1,and the other one is just running a peer2. It means that peer2 needs to connect Fabric Node1 to join channel and get order service. But IPv6 addresses made that occur gRPC connection problem.
Anyone has tried to use Fabric by IPv6?
Does Fabric support IPv6?

```
#Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
#Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer1.org1.example.com peer channel fetch config mychannel.block -c mychannel -o orderer.example.com:7050
#Error: Error connecting due to  rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable
Usage:
  peer channel fetch <newest|oldest|config|(number)> [outputfile] [flags]

Flags:
  -c, --channelID string   In case of a newChain command, the channel ID to create.

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --logging-level string                Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --test.coverprofile string            Done (default "coverage.cov")
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
  -v, --version                             Display current version of fabric peer server
```

The Fabric Node 2's docker-compose.yaml is below.

```
#
# Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
# version: '2'

networks:   
  basic:
services:      
  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    extra_hosts:
      - "orderer.example.com:2000::30:217"
      - "ca.example.com:2000::30:217"
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
#      - orderer.example.com
      - couchdb
    networks:
      - basic

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    networks:
      - basic

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    networks:
        - basic
    depends_on:
    #  - orderer.example.com
       - peer1.org1.example.com
    #  - couchdb
    extra_hosts:
      - "orderer.example.com:2000::30:217"
      - "peer0.org1.example.com:2000::30:217"
      - "peer1.org1.example.com:2000::30:218"
      - "ca.example.com:2000::30:217"
```

Comment: can you paste the error which occured?

Comment: Thx for ur reply. I run startFabric.sh, and it occurs Error: Error connecting due to  rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable . I guess gRPC didn't recongnize IPv6 address. So Does Hyperledger Fabric support IPv6？The full error content is in my question description.

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable ipv6 in docker,for that you have to   Edit or create /etc/docker/daemon.json and set the ipv6 key to true.

```
{
  "ipv6": true
}
```

Save the file.
   Reload the Docker configuration file.

```
$ systemctl reload docker
```

You can now create networks with the --ipv6 flag and assign containers IPv6 addresses using the --ip6 flag.

[this link would help](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/)

Comment: Thx，but it does't work. I checked netstat -a | grep 7050 and this port [::]:7050 is listenning and so as 7051,7053,7054. Then I tried curl [IPv6]:7050 and it also worked. So I guess that it is not because of Docker.Am I right?

Comment: does your compose file have ipv6 tags in it?

Comment: No，does docker-compose support ipv6 tag? I just know Docker has ipv6 tag to build ipv6 network. the single peer node 's docker-compose.yaml has been added in my question description.

Comment: Yes,it supports ipv6 tag.

Comment: Oh..sad. I didn't see ipv6 tag in command line of Docker-compose in this doc.https://docs.docker.com/compose/